# Macbook: boot into GNU Grub after Ubuntu Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, macbook

I am installing Ubuntu (latest version 64 bits) on Macbook Pro 2015. Before Ubuntu, I have already installed Win 10 using bootcamp, and I am installing Ubuntu on an external hard-drive. At the Ubuntu installation page, I have clicked  install boot-loader to the external hard-drive (/dev/Sdb) as well.

**But here comes the problem. Every time when I start my Macbook after a shutdown, it will automatically going into the GNU Grub command line**.

If I do 
`grub>exit`, then it will boot into Mac-OS.

If I hold "Alt option" key during boot-up, I will see only two systems: Mac and Windows. No Ubuntu.

I have to select Windows and then select Ubuntu in order to get into the linux system. The boot-loader setup must have been messed up. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.